# User-provided templates: can they be safe, using EJS?

Tags: node.js, ejs

I would like to create a system where an admin user can set up an HTML-based invoice using EJS, submit it, and then use that EJS to generate invoices.
To do this, I would need them to submit the EJS, store it, and then run it -- server side -- to generate the invoice.

I realise that this is generally a bad idea. At the moment, I am doing my best to put security guidelines in terms of writing the fields with the code in them (only admins can change submit them, etc.). However, I realise that anybody with admin permissions is potentially able to submit a template with malicious code. Questions:

- Is EJS at least *meant* to be safe? (that us, inability to require(), etc.)
- What would you do if you absolutely hard to run user- (or admin-) provided code?

Answer (score 0):

> Is EJS at least meant to be safe? (that us, inability to require(), etc.)

If you're talking about the ejs template itself, than (generally speaking) it mostly affects security on the browser side.
So just to clarify, you can read an EJS template as string and use the [render](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs#usage) method from the ejs library to create the rendered html string to be sent to the client. So basically they cant affect the server unless you rely on data from that template that could affect security for you.

> What would you do if you absolutely hard to run user- (or admin-) provided code?

If I had to go with this approach I would probably add some validations on the template itself. Maybe even parse the DOM check elements are ok it depends on the task and how the EJS varies.
If security is an important issue for you. You can test the ejs when they upload it with some [headless browser](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) to check for anything that is not supposed to be there (unknown ajax requests or script> tags etc)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear at all. The user provides the EJS template, which I store on the server. I then render that EJS template on the *server*, and make a PDF using an headless browser with the resulting HTML...

Comment: I am most worried about a malicious user managing to find a way to save records with the validation code (maybe simply obtaining an admin login) and then generating an invoice -- which would then contain malicious code.

Comment: What do you mean by "the validation code"?
Can you share on of your templates? Or the validation code?

Comment: *template* code. I am sorry, I meant *template* code. Example: `Invoice number <%=job.number%>`